# Need to add video/audio calling feature

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, pubnub

I have an existing application having text based chat functionality using PubNub service. I need to add audio/video calling/recording feature. Which service would be best for this type of scenario? Existing app frontend is on react/redux and backend is on node js

I have researched on Twilio. It has good features but I have doubt about video calling. It is providing some room related apis but I need to implement video calling not any meeting related feature

Comment: "Suggestions" of services and tools are considered off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I have researched on Twilio. It has good features but I have doubt about video calling. It is providing some room related apis but I need to implement  video calling not any meeting related feature.

Comment: In that case, if you have tried that library and need help, create a new question and ask **a specific programming question**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Tok box**  is a good option for your application which is WebRTC based. Opentok provides set of features like-

- video calling
- audio calling
- chat
- screen sharing
- screen recording etc.

Thanks